# Why I am getting import org.springframework.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved error?

Tags: spring, eclipse

All my jar files are linked to build path.Still getting error as 
import org.springframework.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your jar in your classpath, not your modulepath if you are using JDK9+

Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries, in case you have JDK8 add them to your build path if you are having JDK9+ add them to your classpath